# Open Access Form with Filter VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm having trouble opening a form using a filter.  The code that I am trying to run is this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm", , "[ID] = " & Me.MyListBox.Column(0), , acFormEdit, acDialog
```

When I run this line, it opens the form, but does not apply the filter.

The FilterOnLoad property is set to True, and I have verified that it is true in the On Load event.

While in the Form_Load event, Me.FilterOn = False and Me.Filter = "".

What happened to the filter?  What am I doing wrong?  I've tried setting the Me.FilterOn property to True via VBA and then saving the form, but when I open the form again, it is reset to False.

If I put the filter in using VBA and then set the Me.FilterOn property to True, the form correctly filters.  I have verified that the correct value is there for "Me.MyListBox.Column(0)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what the *DoCmd.OpenForm Method* help topic has to say about the *FilterName* parameter:

> A string expression that's the valid name of a query in the current
>   database.

But you're not giving it the name of a query.  I think you actually want the *WhereCondition* parameter instead:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="MyForm", _
    WhereCondition:="[ID] = " & Me.MyListBox.Column(0), _
    DataMode:=acFormEdit, _
    WindowMode:=acDialog
```

Comment: Thanks!  I saw that in the documentation, but then when I set the filter equal to the same string I tried to pass using openform it worked, so I thought that maybe there was something else I needed to do to get it to work.  It's been a long day....

Comment: Yeah, I investigated further and I think the situation is misleading.  When you give `OpenForm` a string value for *FilterName* which does not match the name of a saved query, Access doesn't complain --- it just proceeds to open the form same as if you'd not supplied a *FilterName* in the first place.  Seems to me it should alert you that it can't find the query.  But I really never use *FilterName*; *WhereCondition* is the way to go.  ;-)